# Frequently Camera capture crashing the app without any clue

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, dismiss

I am using UIIMagePicker Controller for capturing image. The camera capture works fine for first 30 to 40 shots but it will crash the app after around 40 captures. I do not get any memory warning or crash report on xcode.

This issue look like memory leak but i have monitored Instruments and memory use is not going more then 60 MB.

The image pick from gallery do not cause this issue.

[image]

Code i am using :-

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:true];
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MMM-dd-yyyy";
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm a";
[timeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];   
NSString *strtime=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@ ",[timeFormatter stringFromDate:now],[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now]];
lblTime.numberOfLines =0;
[lblTime setText:strtime];
[lblTime setHidden:YES];
imgTakenPhoto.image = chosenImage;
[btnCrossOnDentView setHidden:YES];
[btnDoneWithDent setHidden:YES];
App_Delegate.isEdited = YES;
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{

               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
[MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:true];
imagePickerController = nil;
});   }];
}
```

Comment: Please make sure your device is connected with orignal cable.

Comment: I am using original cabels, even when i am not debugging it and using app on device it crashes.

Comment: also share your info.plist file

Comment: check in device crash log. share crash log if there is any.

Comment: I don't think there is anything in plist. Because  I am able to click first 50-60 photos , after that it started crashing.

Comment: No @NinhaHattori there is no crash log, not in Crashlytics also. I just crashes and xcode show that popup only .

Comment: Can you share your code snippet for capturing the photos?

Comment: Its not  possible to add code here i have too lengthy  code

Comment: i am pretty much sure its some kind of memory leak in the code due to that its happening. You can use instrument to analyse that
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/01/25/ios-memory-leak-xcode/

Comment: I used that and i mention in Question i am not facing any memory leak. I already solved that.

Comment: It may be not related to a memory leak, but to too much ressources used (even if there was no peaks shown in XCode). I faced this problem once, especially on old devices while on recent one, I didn't have the issue. I "freed" a little stuff/avoid too many calls.

Comment: But i am facing this issue on every device. Any way to find solution or problem origin ?

Comment: "After capturing 50 to 60 images app crashes randomly." Try to do it differently, are they kept all in memory? Try to save them.

Comment: I am saving all images in document directory and maintaining links only?

Comment: @ChanchalWarde I am facing similar issue with iOS 12, after clicking 15-20 images it stored into UIImage object, it crashes randomly. How had you resolved this ?

Comment: create my own camera module resolved my issue. If you are using UIImagePickerController for capturing images, it will crash if you click images frequently.

Comment: @Mrunal you can also use third party like https://github.com/imaginary-cloud/CameraManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its an iPhone OS issue. I also submitted a report regarding this issue. Same code will run fine in iPad. Report a bug and submit your project.

Answer (score 1):

The best workaround to this is that instead of using UIImagePicker for Camera, use your custom camera view as like WhatsApp, Provide one Capture button onto it to capture as many pics as you want.

Use [AVCapture](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/PhotoCaptureGuide/index.html)

This will completely remove the burden of opening the Camera Controller.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced this problem my current working application. This is because of memory overflow while running your application. I removed unnecessary memory space in application running state. Now my application working fine without any problem.

Comment: i mention my app is not running out of memory.

Comment: This is a real iOS bug. Application memory is not a factor, as mentioned in the OP.