# UIImagePickerController Memory Leak Xcode 9 in Swift 4

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uiimagepickercontroller, swift4, xcode9

In my application I found a memory leak when I used the `UIImagePickerController`, I thought it was my application, but searching for a solution I found an Apple's sample and I also found that this sample has the same memory leak.

You can find the example in the following URL.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196

According to the `UIImagePickerController` documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller

In point 5, thy said that you have to dismiss the image picker using your delegate object, in the Apple's sample the `UIImagePickerDelegate` is doing the dismiss.

The issue is that the memory leak is wasting approximately 21 MB of memory when you select an image and work with it.

**Used Memory without Memory Leak**

[image]

**Used Memory with Memory Leak**

[image]

**Memory Leak**

[image]

This is the code to present the `UIImagePickerController`:

```
@IBAction func showImagePickerForPhotoPicker(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    showImagePicker(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary, button: sender)
}

fileprivate func showImagePicker(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType, button: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // If the image contains multiple frames, stop animating.
    if (imageView?.isAnimating)! {
        imageView?.stopAnimating()
    }
    if capturedImages.count > 0 {
        capturedImages.removeAll()
    }

    imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle =
        (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) ?
            UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen : UIModalPresentationStyle.popover

    let presentationController = imagePickerController.popoverPresentationController
    presentationController?.barButtonItem = button   // Display popover from the UIBarButtonItem as an anchor.
    presentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.any

    if sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera {
        // The user wants to use the camera interface. Set up our custom overlay view for the camera.
        imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = false

        // Apply our overlay view containing the toolar to take pictures in various ways.
        overlayView?.frame = (imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView?.frame)!
        imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = overlayView
    }

    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: {
        // Done presenting.
    })
}
```

And this is the code in the delegate to dismiss the `UIImagePickerController`:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]
    capturedImages.append(image as! UIImage)

    if !cameraTimer.isValid {
        // Timer is done firing so Finish up until the user stops the timer from taking photos.
        finishAndUpdate()
    } else {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        // Done cancel dismiss of image picker.
    })
}

fileprivate func finishAndUpdate() {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: { [weak self] in
        guard let `self` = self else {
            return
        }

        if `self`.capturedImages.count > 0 {
            if self.capturedImages.count == 1 {
                // Camera took a single picture.
                `self`.imageView?.image = `self`.capturedImages[0]
            } else {
                // Camera took multiple pictures; use the list of images for animation.
                `self`.imageView?.animationImages = `self`.capturedImages
                `self`.imageView?.animationDuration = 5    // Show each captured photo for 5 seconds.
                `self`.imageView?.animationRepeatCount = 0   // Animate forever (show all photos).
                `self`.imageView?.startAnimating()
            }

            // To be ready to start again, clear the captured images array.
            `self`.capturedImages.removeAll()
        }
    })
}
```

I'm still looking for a solution, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `self.capturedImages.count` should be `\`self\`.capturedImages`

Comment: Hello @Brandon, thank you for your answer. I'm so sorry, but I don't understand what do you want to accomplish with the change you are suggesting. Could you clarify a little bit?

Comment: @williammr I got same error. Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. So did a ton of other people. Dating back to 2008. Pretty crazy.

- http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3816-uiimagepickercontroller-memory-issues.html
- [UIImagePickerController leaking memory after launch and during taking a picture. Makes app crash after taking more than a 100 pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931452/uiimagepickercontroller-leaking-memory-after-launch-and-during-taking-a-picture)
- [UIImagePickerController Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554225/uiimagepickercontroller-memory-leak)

Unfortunately, the best answer I could find was to use a singleton, which sucks. [i.e. Intentionally retain an instance of UIImagePickerController so you just access that every single time you want to select an image.] This is what others have suggested.

Further, I just spent an hour writing this answer with code that uses a singleton, and I just could not avoid a memory leak [although I thought I had for a second]. Maybe I'm just doing it incorrectly - feel free to try. But I won't post my dysfunctional code as an answer.

The best answer [which is how I solved my problem] is to use a third party pod/library. I used ImagePicker, and it is quick, fast, FREE, beautiful, and NO memory leaks! [MIT License]

Check it out here:
https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker

Comment: Why's this feel like an ad...?

Comment: Hi Chris! It's not! I have no affiliation with ImagePicker, but I am currently using them in my iOS app and can tell you it works great with one drawback - it is difficult to select old pictures because you have to scroll a lot. Otherwise, works great! Cheers, josh @ChrisH